# Redux State throughout Flutter App Not Working

Tags: redux, dart, flutter

I'll preface by saying I am new to Dart and Flutter, so my problem may be obvious but illusive to me so far.

I am working on integrating Redux into my Flutter application. Managing the state in the first view from launch is working as expected. However, when moving to a new "view" through a route name after the launch of the app using.

```
onTap: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        '/dashboard',
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false
    );
},
```

**the Dashboard widget looks like this:**

```
class DashboardHome extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final _l10n = HnLocalizations.of(context);

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: HnAppBar.dashboardSettings(),
      bottomNavigationBar: new HnTabBar(),
      backgroundColor: HnColors.purple,
      body: new StoreConnector(
        converter: (store) => store.state.activeSegment,
        builder: (context, int) => new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage(AppGraphics.bgWorldly),
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              alignment: new Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
            ),
          ),
```

the view throws an error of

> NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'store' was called on null
>   Receiver: null
>   Tried calling: store

**My Main looks like this:**

```
void main() {

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp
  ]);

  final store = new Store(
    appReducer,
    initialState: new HnAppState(),
  );


  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    localizationsDelegates: [
      const HnLocalizationsDelegate(),
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    ],
    supportedLocales: [
      const Locale('en', 'US'),
    ],
    onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) =>
      HnLocalizations.of(context).appName,
    color: HnColors.canvas,
    theme: HnTheme.baseTheme(),
    home: new StoreProvider(
      store: store,
      child:new AppLaunch()
    ),
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      "/home": (BuildContext context) => new WelcomeHome(),
      "/dashboard": (BuildContext context) => new DashboardHome(),
      "/dashboard/settings/account": (BuildContext context) => new AccountProfileSegmentHome()
    },
  ));

}
```

From my understanding of the documentation, once the `StoreProvider` has been set at the top of the application, 'StoreConnector' should have access to `store`. For me, that does not seem to be the case. My first inclination is to pass `store` through the route as in:

```
"/dashboard": (BuildContext context) => new DashboardHome(store)
```

But that seems very off and defeats the purpose of having state accessible from the top of the application.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

What version of flutter_redux do you use ?
New version of flutter_redux add support for dart 2 so you might have to follow "Dart 2 Migration Guide" in https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_redux#-readme-tab-

Have you tried to do something like this:

```
runApp(new StoreProvider(
  store: store,
  child:new MaterialApp(...)
```

Having the StoreProvider in your home page is going to be a problem when you push a different route.
Brian already updated the readme (https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux) with an example where the StoreProvider is at the top of the widget tree.